# Unable to update many-to-many relation using Amplify DataStore

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I have a data model that consist in **three models Profile, Company, Profession**. Profile is a model that I am using in order to link a Cognito user with structured data (such as Company and Profession). **Profile has a many-to-many relation with Company and Profession**.

When we go to towards the [AWS documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/relational/q/platform/js/#many-to-many) it is clear that **we need to create models and then create a new record on the join table** amplify generates when we talk about many-to-many relations.

Nonetheless, the link above doesn't provide information to delete or update many-to-many relations. **I assume that in order to update I need to delete the entry on the Join table and then add the new entries** *(so I avoid duplicated entries and make the job done)*

But when I try to delete an entry from the join table I receive the following error:
`Error of type "ConditionalCheckFailedException"`

Going into the [glossary of errors on DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html) I don't see which condition I may be created from my side unintended as the error suggest my condition is failing

**In summary, in order to allow users to manipulate the professions on their profiles**, I am trying to:

- Add a new entry to the `ProfileProfession` table, and it works

**But when I try to update** by:

- Delete previous entries -> This fails with the error above
- Add new entries -> This works

In case of more context needed here a snippet of the important code I have: https://gist.github.com/duranmla/a8caf14f61ba25fd30610cdb470ee58f

Perhaps my code is not great but I just want to understand how this things work before move further. Thanks in advance to everyone for taking the time to read. ❤️

Answer (score 1):

The answer was:

- Yes, for many-to-many relations you need to manipulate the join Table
- Yes, to update you need to remove or add entries to the join table

Also, the unexpected behaviour one get **by seeing and then not seeing data that is persisted in DynamoDB**, or **Error ConditionalCheckFailedException** one need to:

- Check policies applied to the model
- Understand how DataStore subscription works *(I am currently `DataStore.clear()` on logout and `DataStore.start()` on signIn)*

In my specific case once I did the following:

- Create a `Profile` record on post user confirmation to tie the `Cognito User` to all other models I will have on Amplify Data Model
- Update the authorization Policies on my `Profile` model *(check image below)*
- Clean local data on user logout using `DataStore.clear()`
- Start a subscription when user signIn using `DataStore.start()`

I was able to make things work as expected

---

An image of how the policies look like for `Profile`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqXxk.png

> *Allow any signed-in users authenticated with Cognito User Pool can Read, Update, and Delete Profile* **and** *Enable owner authorization while deny non owners to Update or Delete*

Good resources to check:

- https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/datastore-events/q/platform/js/#usage
- https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/sync/q/platform/js/#clear-local-data
- https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/setup-auth-rules/q/platform/js/#configure-multiple-authorization-types